# Javascript Sum of Array from Classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I am looking to grab all of the numbers which are displayed inside  tags with the class name "prices", and add them together. I have searched for solutions but they are all partial. It seems the javascript doesn't recognize the innerHTML values as numbers.

Comment: Could you add what you've tried so far ?

Comment: `innerText` would be more apropos in this case than `innerHTML`, and `parseFloat` would be what you'd need, not `parseInt`, unless all of the prices are integer values. You might further need a regex to filter out other characters if the prices aren't simple numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <p class="prices">1</p>
    <p class="prices">2</p>
    <p class="prices">3</p>
    <p class="prices">4</p>
    <p class="prices">5</p>

    <script>
        let total = 0;
        document.querySelectorAll(".prices").forEach( price =>{
            total += Number( price.textContent );
            // total += parseInt( price.textContent );
        });
        console.log( total );
    </script>
```

Keep in mind the differences though:

```
Number("2A")
//=> NaN
```

```
parseInt("2A");
//=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let total = 0;
$(".price").each(function(){
  total = total + Number($(this).text())
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s563mkge/